# delete a row from table based on a specific association

Tags: mysql, sql, symfony

I have two tables page and paragraph(a One to One relation ship). each page has only one paragraph. what I want is to see a row from the paragraph table deleted once the corresponding row on the page table gets deleted.

Comment: Have a look at CONSTRAINT .. ON DELETE .. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1-olh/de/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html

Comment: Perhaps you could post the entities so we may see the definition of the relationship?

Comment: I am using symfony2, should I post the classes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use something like

```
@ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Paragraph", mappedBy="page",cascade={"persist", "remove"})
```

Answer (score 2):

In your entity mapping you should use cascade property like:

```
cascade = {"persist","remove"}
```

example :

Page Class:

```
      <?php

      /** @ORM\Entity **/
        class Page
        {

          /**
            * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Paragraph", mappedBy="page",cascade={"persist", "remove"})
            **/
          private $paragraph;

           }
```

Paragraph Class:

```
         <?php

           /** @ORM\Entity **/
           class Paragraph
              {
               /**
                 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Paragraph", inversedBy="paragraph",cascade={"persist", "remove"})
                 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="page_id", referencedColumnName="id")
                 **/
                private $page
                }
```